# How to join two table columns and store in a separate new table in sqlite3

Tags: django, sqlite

I Have two tables

1. **Name-fields(user_Id,name)**
2. **Type-fields(user_Id,meaning)**

These are my two tables and i want to copy these data and merge them into a new separate table like this using sqlite3

output table-**fields(name,meaning)**

make me out of this question

What I have tried:

i have tried update method but did not got an clear output

Comment: [`CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#createtabas)

Comment: Thank you sir , but i could not find a solution in that link can u provide a different solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (I haven't tested):

```
CREATE TABLE outputfields AS
SELECT name, meaning
FROM namefields N JOIN typefields T ON N.user_id = T.user_id;
```

Comment: Sir,Thank a lot it works and i have changed CREATE TABLE as INSERT INTO  because i want it with already existing table.

Comment: Then "store it in a separate **new** table" might have been an unfortunate choice of title... :)

Comment: but i have a small problem i dint want duplicates in name field

Comment: You can use the new `UPSERT` if your SQLite is new enough, or `INSERT OR REPLACE`; be sure to declare `name` as either `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE`.

Comment: OK sir i will try with your suggestion , Thank you a lot